# Ajax & PHP - Why do code work on local server, but it don't work on hosting?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, synchronous

What should I do to ajax work on the hosting? I try to make progressbar. I want to `"echo <p>$i</p>"`was showed at once as iteration finished. On localserver `"echo <p>$i</p>"` worked and showed $i at once as iteration finished. On hosting `"echo <p>$i</p>"` worked and showed $i only after script execution. Code work on local server, but don't work on the hosting. I think trouble in settings php on the hosting or request headers. I tried find solution of this trouble, but didn't find. Help me, please!

PHP & HTML Code:

```
<?php

if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {

    $i = 0;

    echo "<p>$i</p>";
    flush();
    ob_flush();

    while ($i < 5) {
        $i++;
        echo "<p>$i</p>";
        flush();
        ob_flush();
        sleep(1);
    }
    exit();
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Output PHP Script Progress via Ajax - Basic Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <h2>Output PHP Script Progress via Ajax - Basic Example</h2>
    <p>Cick button below to run script.</p>
    <form class="" role="form" action="/basic.php" method="post">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Execute Long PHP Script</button>
    </form>

    <div id="progress"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./dist/script-basic.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

JS Code with Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").submit(function(e) {
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr("action"),
            xhrFields: {
                onprogress: function(e) {
                    console.log(e.target.responseText), $("#progress").html(e.target.responseText)
                }
            },
            success: function(e) {
                console.log(e), $("#progress").html(e + "<h1>done!</h1>")
            }
        }), e.preventDefault()
    })
});
```

Comment: Not all servers provide `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH`. [Ref](https://davidwalsh.name/detect-ajax)

Comment: @KIKOSoftware  That may be true, but it's not the case here.  That would prevent the PHP code from running at all.  That's not the behavior OP is noting.

Comment: @Oleg  What you're currently doing doesn't really need an ajax call at all, and everything could be done client-side.  Do you have a real-world/practical example of what you might really be wanting to do?  The actual use-case would dictate the answer, which might even be "you can't because that's not how ajax works"

Comment: I want to $i was output at moment as was finished every iteration. On localserver $i was output gradually. On hosting $i was output only after full script finished. I think that problem is buffer. It needs to be filled. Am I right?